# Why do I have to restart live-server to see changes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser, npm-live-server

I have a new laptop and have installed VSCode and nodeJS to continue working on my projects. Unfortunately I have to restart the server every time to see my saved changes. Here is what is displayed in the console:

[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS....

I have also downloaded the live server extension. When I start this I get the following error message in the console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).

Can someone please help me?